# Beginning Ocaml - test cases returning unimplemented

Tags: ocaml

right now I'm getting started with Ocaml but I'm having trouble with it. When I input this code, my test cases report that the code is unimplemented even though I implemented it. Is there some kind of syntax error somewhere? I am really unused to the language so yeah. Thanks in advance.

```
let rec move_robot (pos: int) (dir: string) (num_moves: int) : int =
   let new_position=pos in
       if dir="forward" then new_position=pos+num_moves in
       else if dir="backward" then new_position=pos-num_moves in
       if new_position>=99 then 99
       else if new_position<=0 then 0
       else new_position

let test () : bool =
  (move_robot 10 "forward" 3) = 13
  ;; run_test "move_robot forward 3" test 

let test () : bool =
  (move_robot 1 "backward" 4 ) = 0
  ;; run_test "move_robot backward 4" test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it's because you have syntax errors everywhere and `move_robot` was never loaded into the top level. `Syntax Error` messages should be pretty obvious, regardless your conceptual mistake is common in starting out functional programming in OCaml.

Although the first `if` statement has an extraneous `in`, it also should not set a variable in its statement but return some value. In general the way in which you deal w/ and set `new_position` is very C like, and if you fixed the first syntax error you'd instantly find that you never changed the value of `new_position`. The `if` statement (and anything else for the most part) should return a value, not attempt to mutate a variable in a larger scope --one would use references for that, which are un-necessary here.

```
let new_position =
    if dir = "forward" then pos+num_moves
    else if dir = "backward" then pos-num_moves
    else failwith ("Invalid Direction: "^dir)
in
```

as you can see, we don't ever try to modify `new_position`; which aligns with immutability that functional programmers love. Notice also that you will get a type-checking error if you don't include the final `else` statement. Excluding it is syntax sugar for returning `unit` but you return an integer. Even better (and I think usually cleaner than an `if` statement) is to use pattern matching,

```
let new_position = match dir with
    | "forward"  -> pos+num_moves
    | "backward" -> pos-num_moves
    | _          -> failwith ("Invalid Direction: "^dir)
in
```

I know you're starting out, so you can leave this to another day but I'll just mention (without explanation) that you should use variants or possibly polymorphic variants instead of checking for strings directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! My first language was C so yeah; it's so weird thinking of declaring variables with ifs inside the declaration.

Comment: I know this is pedantic but these aren't variables; they're values. Variables implies mutability.

Comment: It's probably equally pedantic, but these *are* variables. 50 years of terminology abuse have just made most imperative programmers forget what that actually means in the good old mathematical sense. The mutable kind of variable is more accurately called a mutable reference, a cell, or some other synonym. ;)